# What does * html body mean?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, internet-explorer

I found this in a WordPress css file and I don't understand it:

```
html { margin-top: 28px !important; }
* html body { margin-top: 28px !important; }
```

Why is the second line needed and what does * html body select?

Comment: Google: "star html hack"

Comment: [This site](http://css-tricks.com/how-to-create-an-ie-only-stylesheet/) (towards the bottom after the conditional comments section) has a decent list of IE CSS hacks, including the `* html` selector hack. @Adrift FYI Your link is for a `*` preceeding a rule, as opposed to this question which is for a `*` preceeding a selector.

Answer (score 3):

It matches "A body element that is a descendant of an html element that is a descendant of any element".

This is impossible in HTML.

(But a bug that used to exist in IE means it will match in old versions of that browser).

Answer (score 0):

It's a hack to declare css styles that only the IE browser can use...

Newer browsers will ignore the CSS declaration...